# condition on dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D dimensional NumPy array of shape `(120, 16)` which consists of phase oscillators `(16)` value over time step `(120)`

from this array of shape `(120, 16)` I want to put something like an if condition, where I am able to only take values of phase oscillators belonging to an interval, `[0, pi]` for example.

I am new to working with NumPy so any help?

Comment: The best answer to your question depends on what you intend to do with the filtered data. You either have to pick the conditioned elements in a 1-D array or use masked arrays with masked elements that do not meet the condition. Maybe you can elaborate on your next task so we can help better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayFinal = array1[array1 < 10]
arrayFinal = array1[(array1> 5) & (array1< 20)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this (assuming your original `(120, 16)` array were called `my_array`):

```
valid_oscillators_mask = np.all(np.logical_and(my_array > 0, my_array < np.pi), axis = 0)
valid_oscillators = my_array[:, valid_oscillators_mask]
```